# Function is not executing after ajax call

Tags: jquery, grails

Below is the piece of sample code , i am trying to execute a javascript function
on button click, which sends a ajex call which refresh tr , but openEditPage(this); is not execute after that first refresh

```
<tbody>
  <g:each in="${item}" var="value">
    <tr id='tableRow"${value.id}"'>
      <td width="20"><input type="checkbox" name="tagChekBox" class="checkbox" value="${value.id}" style=""></td>
      <td>${value.Name}</td>
      <td>${value.noOfTags}</td>
      <td>
        <div class="add-remove-icon">
          <a href="#" class="icon-edit-sign edit-btn" value="editable-row${value.id}" onClick ="openEditPage(this);"></a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="editable-row" id="editable-row${value.id}"></div>
        <div>
          <input type="text" id="${value.id}" value="${value.Name}" name="tagcatName" class="margin-none" >
        </div>
        <button class="saveTagCategorButton">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </g:each>
</tbody>

<script>
  /*this finction show the div of editable row */
  function openEditPage(object){
    var id =($(object).parent().find('a').attr('value'));
    $('#'+id).slideDown();

    return false;
  }

  $(".saveTagCategorButton").click(function(){
    jQuery.ajax({

      success: function(response,textStatus){
        var trElement=that.parent().parent().parent().parent();
        trElement .slideUp();
        trElement.prev().html(response);
      },
    });
    return false;
  });
</script>

response contains--

<tr id='tableRow"${value.id}"'>
  <td width="20">
    <input type="checkbox" name="tagChekBox" class="checkbox" value="${value.id}" style="">
  </td>
  <td>${value.Name}</td>
  <td>${value.noOfTags}</td>
  <td>
    <div class="add-remove-icon">
      <a href="#" class="icon-edit-sign edit-btn" value="editable-row${value.id}" onClick ="openEditPage(this);"></a>
    </div>
  </td>
```

Comment: Add a handler for error:  to see if anything is reported there.

Comment: What's the comma doing here: `jQuery.ajax({ , success:`?

Comment: To which URL are you making the AJAX request? I see only a success handler there..

Comment: why you have used `return false` in your function call?

Answer (score 1):

you should also modify your HTML structure and script a bit as well, `value` is not the supported attribute of `<a>` tag. Use `id = "editable-row${value.id}"` instead.

change this line

```
($(object).parent().find('a').attr('value'));
```

with this one

```
$(object).prop('id'); //this will yield the same result
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" class="icon-edit-sign edit-btn" id="editable-row${value.id}" onClick ="openEditPage(event, this);">Link</a>
```

**Script:**

```
function openEditPage(event, object){
 var id = $(object).prop('id');
 $('#'+id).slideDown();

 event.preventDefault();
}

$(function(){
$(".saveTagCategorButton").click(function(){
  jQuery.ajax({
   //other jquery ajax parameters,
    success: function(response,textStatus){
      /*
      * this is not a good approach, calling parent() to parent() again and again,
      * use something more appropriate and less complex for jQuery to parse the DOM, I would have done this but I am unsure of your requirements
      */
      var trElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();  //use 'this' instead of 'that' wrapped in jQuery.
      trElement.slideUp();
      trElement.prev().html(response);
     },
    }); 
 });       
});
```

Again this line `var trElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();` will get the whole `<tbody>`.

`return false` will cancel the default action of the control and also stops the propagation of further actions bind to that control. So always use `event.preventDefault()` if cancelling only the default action and so as `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 0):

This line: 
`var id =($(object).parent().find('a').attr('value'));`

should be:

`var id =($(object).parent().find('a').attr('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirement,

```
function openEditPage(object){

// Not sure why the line below is needed.
// 'id' will return you the 'object' as well.
var id =($(object).parent().find('a').attr('value'));

$('#'+id).slideDown(); // Change to $(object).slideDown();

return false;
}
```